# When using ehcache, what synchronization do I need to do?

Tags: ehcache

Let's say I start with a single CacheManager like this:
    private static CacheManager manager = CacheManager.create();

When I call getCache or addCache do I need to synchronize on the CacheManager first?

When I call put or get on the Cache, should I synchronize on the Cache first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[These docs](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager.html) imply that you have to synchronize on the CacheManager instance, as, for example, [addCache](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager.html#addCache%28net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache%29) throws an exception if the given cache "already exists" in the cache.